# Sequelize: Apply Filters after all Joins

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a Sequelize findAll() method that gets the record after some Joins and Filters. A raw SQL is being converted to the Sequelize ORM query. The query ran by the Sequelize ORM is as follows:

```
SELECT 
`tableA`.* 
FROM
  (SELECT 
    `tableA`.`i_id`,
    COUNT(
      DISTINCT (
        tableA.c_id
      )
    ) AS `total`,
    `ModelB`.`title` AS `ModelB.title`,
    `ModelB`.`id` AS `ModelB.id` 
  FROM
    `tableA` AS `aliasA` 
    INNER JOIN `tableB` AS `aliasB` 
      ON `aliasA`.`c_id` = `aliasB`.`id` 
    INNER JOIN `tableC` AS `aliasC` 
      ON `aliasA`.`clientID` = `aliasC`.`id` 
      AND `aliasC`.`a` = '483' 
      AND `aliasC`.`s` IN (0, '', NULL) 
    INNER JOIN `tableD` AS `aliasD` 
      ON `aliasA`.`id` = `aliasD`.`id` 
      AND `aliasD`.`id` IN (100, 101)
  WHERE `aliasA`.`state` = 'on' 
    AND (
      `aliasA`.`time_added` >= '2012-02-01 00:00:00' 
      AND `aliasA`.`time_added` <= '2017-08-24 12:31:13'
    ) 
  LIMIT 100) AS `aliasA` 
  INNER JOIN `tableE` AS `aliasE` 
    ON `aliasD.uid` = `aliasE`.`uid` 
    AND `aliasD`.`object_id` = '483' 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `tableF` AS `aliasF` 
    ON `aliasA`.`id` = `aliasF`.`uid` 
    AND `aliasF`.`share` IN (100, 101);
```

My requirement is to first apply all the Joins and then filter the by applying the WHERE clauses with ANDs and ORs. Finally, I need to apply 'Group', 'Order' and 'Limit' clauses on the coluns of associated tables. Please let me understand, I'm new to Node world. I was unable to find anything like this on Sequelize official documentation.

Comment: did you find a solution for this? I just encounter the same issue on my side